# web_accessible_resources in manifest v3 Chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that comes with with some fonts. To make them usable from the extension, my manifest v2 includes

```json
...
"web_accessible_resources": ["fonts/*"],
...
```

This works well. I looked into upgrading to manifest v3. Here, I'm getting

```
Error at key 'web_accessible_resources'. Parsing array failed at index 0: expected dictionary, got string
```

Alright, so [I need `"resources"` and `"matches"` or `"extensions"`.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/#manifest-declaration). Since the extension needs the fonts on all pages, let's try and specify the chrome extension ID:

```json
...
"web_accessible_resources": [
  {
    "resources": ["fonts/*"],
    "extensions": ["mychromeextensionid"]
  }
],
...
```

```
Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'. Entry must at least have resources, and one other valid key.
```

Hm, still not working. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Why is this marked duplicat/closed. I am also encountering this error where I cant access my resources using my extensionId .
The linked question has a solution using all_urls but im not sure if thats a good thing to do